# how to conversation template click input another value in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want the template text to be [item], but the value I'm actually sending is thrown as a different value.

for example

```
conversation-drivers {
        conversation-driver {
          template (text : itemName, ClickRealValue : itemVal)  <--- I want it
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done in Bixby (and it is by design).

Tap conversation driver text would result **the exact same text** (nature language utterance) passed as a continuation.

This makes sense because:

1. User must know what he/she is selecting.
2. Conversation driver act as if holding Bixby button and say the utterance.

It is nature to use shorter utterance since longer conversation drivers would be pushed outside the screen. All developer need to do is add training examples to Bixby to support the shorter utterance as continuation.

Comment: @박동석, Remember that a conversation driver is supposed to be showing the user examples of what they can say. That is why they can only run the exact same text (nature language utterance).